# Is it a good idea to use an ORM for Android apps?

Tags: android, database, performance, orm, abstraction

Is it a good idea to use an ORM (Object Relational Mapper) like:

- ORMLite
- ActiveAndroid

for Android apps.

The abstraction layer this technique adds has itself calculation and memory overhead. Since, those resources and the battery lifetime are mostly very limited I would think 'no', but on the other hand it makes the code much cleaner, because one almost never has to write raw queries.

- What are the pros and cons?
- What is recommended?
- If it is recommended, which one should I use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of May 18, 2017, Google introduced [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) at I/O '17 as replacement for raw SQLite queries. So, at least this ORM is now officially recommended.

Comment: Room supports only basic SQLite features. For example, it does not support `upsert`: https://sqlite.org/lang_upsert.html

Answer (score 1):

OrmLite use SQLite database underneath. It just generates database schema using annotation processor. It is a good idea if your project allows using third- party opensource libraries. However, you should incapsulate all implementation - dependent features - 'Dao' pattern. By doing so, you'll be able to switch between database implementations. BE careful with Realm though. It is a very powerful database, but if you use it incorrectly, it can ruin your architecture. Always specify Dao interface before implementing database itself.

Comment: so, the annotation processor runs at compile-time and gives no runtime performance decrease?

Comment: It creates schema at compile time and then use reflections. It gives some decrease, but those a very small compared to database operation time

Comment: I see, but why is reflection still necessary? All the code could have been generated from the annotations? So, if I aim for performance, should I avoid ORM?

Comment: ok, I see... so, is it actually recommended by Google to use an ORM? Which one should I use (edit of my question).

Comment: Usually I use OrmLite or (sometimes) Realm, because those are easy to use. Realm is a native noSql database, I use it when app should store some readings on disc, in separate files.